# using javascript to load json data from google maps

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

So, this is the code I have, console.log gives me the right value, but the function doesn't return the value, even if the return is inside the timeout.  I must be doing something wrong.

```
function countyfinder(address){


var rr =$.getJSON('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + address.replace(" ", "%20")).done(function(data) {
var county = data.results[0].address_components[3].short_name;
//return county;//data is the JSON string
});return rr;};

function calculatetax(address, price){
var j = countyfinder(address);
setTimeout(function(){var k = j["responseJSON"]['results'][0]['address_components'][3]['short_name'];
console.log(k);//return k won't work in here either
}, 1000); return k
};
```

Comment: 1. why are you using the Geocoding Web Service from javascript, use the Google Maps Javascript API v3 Geocoding Service 2. $.getJSON is asynchronous

Comment: `rr` is a promise, not the data you think it is

Comment: 1.  I'll look into it now 2. is there a way to wait for asynchronous data?

Answer (score 0):

this is what I ended up with:

```
    var jq = document.createElement('script');
    jq.src = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);


    function getCounty(address) {
      var country;
      var baseApiUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json";
      var query = "?address=" + encodeURIComponent(address);
      var queryUrl = baseApiUrl + query;

      $.ajax({
        url: queryUrl,
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          county = gmapsExtractByType(data, "administrative_area_level_2 political");
        }
      });

      return countr.long_name;
    }

    function gmapsExtractByType(json, type) {
      return json.results[0].address_components.filter(function(element) {
        return element.types.join(" ") === type;
      })[0];
    }      
    console.log( getCounty("100 wacko lane ohio") );
```

I had to use a synchronous request by changing some settings in the ajax request.  The drawback of this is that the browser will be locked up until you get a request response, which can be bad on a slow connection or a connection with an unreliable server.  With google, most of the time, I don't think that will happen.